# How do I insert spaces back into string after removing them

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to : 
1) Remove spaces from a given string 
2) From the removed spaces string, insert the spaces to where they were original
3) Final result should be the original text.

string original = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    string removeSpace, withSpace;

```
int foo[8];
int count = 0;

cout << original << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++)
{
    if (char(int(original[i])) == 32)
    {
        foo[count] = i;

        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        removeSpace += original[i];
    }
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << "Spaces at : " << foo[i] << endl;
}
cout << "==========With spaces remove==========" << endl;
cout << removeSpace << endl;
count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < removeSpace.size(); i++)
{
    if (foo[count] == i)
    {
        withSpace += ' ';
        count++;

    }
    withSpace += removeSpace[i];
}

cout << "==========With spaces inserted==========";
cout << "\n" << withSpace << endl;
```

This is what i am getting:

The quickb rownfo xjum psover thela zydo g

How do I insert them back to make it 
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Answer (score 3):

It's clear what the problem is from looking at your output. In `foo` you are storing the indexes of the spaces *before any spaces have been removed*. But when you put back the spaces you are comparing `foo` with `i` which is the index *after the spaces have been removed*. This is not a meaningful thing to do. You just need to adjust your algorithm to account for this difference.

Here's a minimal adjustment to your code that fixes the problem. By comparing `foo[cout]` with the size of the `withSpace` string I'm comparing like with like. Both `foo[count]` and `withSpace.size()` are indexes and sizes of the string *after spaces have been added*.

```
for (int i = 0; i < removeSpace.size(); i++)
{
    if (foo[count] == withSpace.size())
    {
        withSpace += ' ';
        count++;
    }
    withSpace += removeSpace[i];
}
```

Full code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HkLAsQvZS).

This code

```
if (char(int(original[i])) == 32)
```

is a good example of doing a simple thing in a complicated way. This is better

```
if (original[i] == ' ')
```